# heuristics for determing if cayley tales are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, cayley-table

I've recently plunged into understanding the basics of group theory, mostly out of sheer fascination, and all sorts of interesting questions are coming to mind. Please remember I'm new at this; if your response to "Do not bite the tyro" is "A true mathematician does not coddle the weak", please stop reading here and move on. You'll save us both a lot of irritation.

I am curious what rules exist to determine whether two groups could be isomorphic, based on their Cayley tables. I'm familiar already with counting the number of elements of order two ([How to determine if groups are isomorphic using cayley table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415907/how-to-determine-if-groups-are-isomorphic-using-cayley-table?rq=1)) but wonder if any other "tricks" are known that can reduce the amount of brute force searching for possible isomorphisms.

More precisely: If I have two Cayley tables S and T, and want to know if there is a permutation P that will take S to T, we know the answer is No if S and T have different numbers of elements of order 2. Are there any other tricks that tell us there is no such permutation; or, better yet, tell us that there certainly is such a permutation, without having to do a brute search for the permutation?

Comment: There are lots of tricks for determining that they *aren't* isomorphic, e.g. counting the elements of order $3$, order $4$, etc. Tricks for determining that they *are* isomorphic are harder to come by and at some point you should stop using Cayley tables and use a better way to represent groups. Cayley tables are an extremely inefficient way to describe groups because much of the information in them is redundant.

Comment: You can do a bit better than trying all permutations. A group of order $N$ has a generating set of size $O(\log N)$, and an isomorphism is determined by the images of the generators, which results in an $O(N^{\log N})$ algorithm for isomorphism testing. But that's still not good, and one feels that there should be algorithms that are polynomial in $N$ and possibly even in $\log N$.